# When I add whatsapp_share2: ^2.0.2 this library I cant install pod

Tags: flutter, dart

Please check this image when I add whatsapp_share2: ^2.0.2 this plugin I can't install pod and they give me "No podspec found for `whatsapp_share2` in `.symlinks/plugins/whatsapp_share2/ios`" and also I use this library for share image in direcly Whatsapp so please help me to find a solution

[check this image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mAzhE_BWeodQxnuMLjgV3trEOyQZW85t/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: check whether you have ios/podfile or not?

Comment: already have a podfile but not working

Comment: does that podfile have this -

target 'Runner' do
    use_frameworks!

Comment: yes, I already add this line but it's not working

Comment: Any solution....?

Comment: Check out the solution to this https://github.com/ankushmishra2903-official/whatsapp_share2/issues/4#issuecomment-1363030915

Answer (score 5):

I found the solution by doing this:

1. Rename **podspec** file in **.symlinks** folder

> ios/.symlinks/plugins/whatsapp_share2/ios/flutter_share.podspec

to :

> **ios/.symlinks/plugins/whatsapp_share2/ios/whatsapp_share2.podspec**

2. Inside this previous **whatsapp_share2.podspec** file

· Edit the line no. 5 s.name to :

> **s.name = 'whatsapp_share2'**

3. Inside in same folder go to **Classes** folder and edit in file named **FlutterSharePlugin.m**

☞ ios/.symlinks/plugins/whatsapp_share2/ios/Classes/FlutterSharePlugin.m
changing the lines:

> #import "WhatsappShare.h"
>
> #import <whatsapp_share/whatsapp_share-Swift.h>

to:

> **#import "FlutterSharePlugin.h"**
>
> **#import <whatsapp_share2/whatsapp_share2-Swift.h>**

Answer (score 2):

Go to:

> iOS > .symlinks/plugins/whatsapp_share2/iOS/

There is a file named `flutter_share.podspec`

Rename this file to `whatsapp_share2.posdpec` and paste the following content:

```
# To learn more about a Podspec see http://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html
#
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name             = 'whatsapp_share2'
  s.version          = '0.0.1'
  s.swift_version    = '4.1'
  s.summary          = 'Simple way to share a message, link or files from your flutter app'
  s.description      = <<-DESC
Simple way to share a message, link or files from your flutter app
                       DESC
  s.homepage         = 'http://example.com'
  s.license          = { :file => '../LICENSE' }
  s.author           = { 'Your Company' => 'email@example.com' }
  s.source           = { :path => '.' }
  s.source_files = 'Classes/**/*'
  s.public_header_files = 'Classes/**/*.h'
  s.dependency 'Flutter'

  s.ios.deployment_target = '8.0'
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the file name according to your plugin/package name.

Look for the file `flutter_share.podspec` in `your_project/ios/.symlinks/plugins/whatsapp_share/ios/`.

Then change the file name to the package name, here `whatsapp_share`.

Next, try to install the pod by running the command `pod install`.

If you get an error like `WhatsappShare.h` not found.

Go to `Classes/` folder in same directory and open `FlutterSharePlugin.m` and paste the below code.

```
#import "FlutterSharePlugin.h"
#import <whatsapp_share/whatsapp_share-Swift.h>

@implementation WhatsappShare
+ (void)registerWithRegistrar:(NSObject<FlutterPluginRegistrar>*)registrar {
  [SwiftWhatsappShare registerWithRegistrar:registrar];
}
@end
```

This will solve your problem. And if you try to change the library dependency you need to do these steps again.